# When to use from_json filter in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

When should I use the `from_json` [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) in Ansible?

I found out that using it sometimes has and sometimes have no effect.

Please consider the following example which illustrates the inconsistency I am getting.

<sup>Included in reverse order are: the questions - expected result - actual result - the playbook - the data. The data is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41261680/2947502) and the playbook is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41262712/2947502).</sup>

- The question(s):

  Why storing the left part (before `json_query`) of the following expression in a variable and then using `json_query` on the variable causes the expression to be evaluated differently?

  ```
  "{{ lookup('file','test.json') | json_query(query) }}"
  ```

  Why does adding `from_json` filter alter the results (but does not if processing a variable):

  ```
  "{{ lookup('file','test.json') | from_json | json_query(query) }}"
  ```
- Expected result:

  Last four tasks should give the same result. Alternatively, last two tasks should give the same result as previous two tasks.
- Actual result (last four tasks only):

  One task result differs.

  ```
  TASK [This query is run against lookup value with from_json stored in a variable] ***
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": [
          678
      ]
  }

  TASK [This query is run against lookup value without from_json stored in a variable] ***
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": [
          678
      ]
  }

  TASK [This query is run directly against lookup value with from_json] **********
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": [
          678
      ]
  }

  TASK [This query is run directly against lookup value without from_json - the result is empty - why?] ***
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": ""
  }
  ```
- The playbook:

  ```
  ---
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    connection: local
    tasks:   
      - set_fact:
          from_lookup_with_from_json: "{{ lookup('file','test.json') | from_json }}"

      - set_fact:
          from_lookup_without_from_json: "{{ lookup('file','test.json') }}"

      - name: Save the lookup value stored in a variable in a file for comparison
        copy: content="{{ from_lookup_with_from_json }}" dest=./from_lookup_with_from_json.txt

      - name: Save the lookup value stored in a variable in a file for comparison (they are the same)
        copy: content="{{ from_lookup_without_from_json }}" dest=./from_lookup_without_from_json.txt

      - name: This query is run against lookup value with from_json stored in a variable
        debug: msg="{{ from_lookup_with_from_json | json_query(query) }}"
        vars:
          query: "Foods[].{id: Id, for: (Tags[?Key=='For'].Value)[0]} | [?for=='Tigger'].id"

      - name: This query is run against lookup value without from_json stored in a variable
        debug: msg="{{ from_lookup_without_from_json | json_query(query) }}"
        vars:
          query: "Foods[].{id: Id, for: (Tags[?Key=='For'].Value)[0]} | [?for=='Tigger'].id"

      - name: This query is run directly against lookup value with from_json
        debug: msg="{{ lookup('file','test.json') | from_json | json_query(query) }}"
        vars:
          query: "Foods[].{id: Id, for: (Tags[?Key=='For'].Value)[0]} | [?for=='Tigger'].id"

      - name: This query is run directly against lookup value without from_json - the result is empty - why?
        debug: msg="{{ lookup('file','test.json') | json_query(query) }}"
        vars:
          query: "Foods[].{id: Id, for: (Tags[?Key=='For'].Value)[0]} | [?for=='Tigger'].id"
  ```
- The data (`test.json`):

  ```
  { "Foods" :
    [ { "Id": 456
      , "Tags":
        [ {"Key":"For", "Value":"Heffalump"}
        , {"Key":"Purpose", "Value":"Food"}
        ]
      }
    , { "Id": 678
      , "Tags":
        [ {"Key":"For", "Value":"Tigger"}
        , {"Key":"Purpose", "Value":"Food"}
        ]
      }
    , { "Id": 911
      , "Tags":
        [ {"Key":"For", "Value":"Roo"}
        , {"Key":"Purpose", "Value":"Food"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`json_query` requires Python object (dict) as input, if you feed it with string, it gives empty string as result.

You get different result because of Ansible templating engine tricky work.
*I should definitely write a post about it on my site...*

After evaluating jijna2 expression Ansible try to cast complex types to Python objects (like dict or list). See my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41147661/2795592) answer.

In your case:

1.

```
- set_fact:
    from_lookup_with_from_json: "{{ lookup('file','test.json') | from_json }}"
```

`from_lookup_with_from_json` is a dict, because you manually convert JSON-string from file to dict with `from_json` filter.

2.

```
- set_fact:
    from_lookup_without_from_json: "{{ lookup('file','test.json') }}"
```

`from_lookup_with_from_json` becomes dict, because Ansible converts it when jinja2 expression ends with `}}`. So `from_json` is actually unnecessary as *the last* filter in chain.

3.

```
  debug: msg="{{ lookup('file','test.json') | from_json | json_query(query) }}"
```

Again, you manually convert JSON-string here. So `json_query` get dict as input.

4.

```
  debug: msg="{{ lookup('file','test.json') | json_query(query) }}"
```

In this case you feed JSON-string (not dict) as input to `json_query` filter. As everything happens inside one jinja2 expression, Ansible doesn't attempt to convert anything in between.

You can also get empty string result with a variable this way:

```
- set_fact:
    from_lookup_force_string: "{{ lookup('file','test.json') | string }}"
```

In this case `from_lookup_force_string` will not be converted by Ansible tempating engine, and `json_query` will give you empty response on it.

Comment: `json_query` is a poorly named filter since it operates on dicts not JSON.  Perhaps dict_query would be better.

Comment: ``json_query`` operates on JSON including [lists](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#id3), of course.  For example, quoting from [Wildcard Expressions](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#wildcard-expressions): ``The [*] syntax applies to a list type and the * syntax applies to a hash type.``

Comment: For the record: [Ansible json_query issue fixed in 2.10](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299#issuecomment-331068246).