# Ansible - is it possible to register multiple variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a python script which is returning / print two lists.

**test.py**

```
def getHosts():
        Pool1=[x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x]
        Pool2=[x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x]
        Print pool1,pool2
        Return pool1,pool2

getHosts()
```

My playbook looks like:

```
     -task:
      name: get the hosts
      command: /test.py
      register: result
```

Now, is it possible to fetch out the pool1 and pool2 seperately from the registered variable result ? If yes, please show me an example.

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don’t you simply produce a JSON object?

Comment: @techraf you mean to say return a JSON from python? Yes, i can do that but how to read JSON object from register variable. (Very new to ansible. Pls share some chunks of code)

Comment: What do you mean by “how to read”?

Comment: If I do like register:result where result is the JSON. Then how to read the objects from the 'result' variable in playbook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Produce JSON and feed it to Ansible. It will automatically create an appropriate data structure:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - command: 'echo { \"Pool1\": \"[x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x]\", \"Pool2\": \"[x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x]\" }'
      register: my_output
    - set_fact:
        my_variable: "{{ my_output.stdout | from_json }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Pool1 is {{ my_variable.Pool1 }} and Pool2 is {{ my_variable.Pool2 }}"
```

---

Result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Pool1 is [x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x] and Pool2 is [x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x]"
}
```

---

<sup>Depending on how you later use the variable, you might/might not need to `from_json` filter (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263933/when-to-use-from-json-filter-in-ansible)).</sup>